# Selected table cell information not displaying in detail view using core data, no error

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

When a table cell is selected, I want it to populate the textfields on my detail view after segue.

Here is one way I found on this site (I've tried other ways I saw here but had errors/ issues translating the code to use with core data and/or custom cells) that doesn't return errors but does not fill out the fields

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        //(print(tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PartyCell", for: indexPath)))

        //  get selected row (party)
        let party = parties[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject

        //  create custom cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PartyCell",
                                                 for: indexPath) as! PartyCell

        //  Update the custom cell labels with information from record
        cell.nameLabel?.text = party.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
        cell.sizeLabel.text = party.value(forKeyPath: "size") as? String
        cell.contactLabel.text = party.value(forKeyPath: "contact") as? String
        cell.locationLabel.text = party.value(forKeyPath: "location") as? String

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {


        // Create a variable that you want to send based on the destination view controller
        // Get a reference to the data by using indexPath shown below
        let party = parties[indexPath.row]

        // Create an instance of DestinationViewController and pass the variable
        let destinationVC = DetailViewController()


        destinationVC.nameField.text = party.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
        destinationVC.sizeField.text = party.value(forKeyPath: "size") as? String
        destinationVC.contactField.text = party.value(forKeyPath: "contact") as? String
        destinationVC.locationField.text = party.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String


        // Let's assume that the segue name is called playerSegue
        // This will perform the segue and pre-load the variable for you to use
        destinationVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)

    }
```

And here is the detail view with the outlet connections established

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DetailViewController: UIViewController
{

    //let party = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Party", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Party


    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sizeField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var contactField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationField: UITextField!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three fatal mistakes:

1. `DetailViewController()` is not the instance in the storyboard.
2. Even if it was the outlets are not connected yet right after initializing the controller.
3. You have to perform the segue on the main view controller, not on the `DetailViewController`.

The solutions:

1. In `didSelectRowAt` call `self.performSegue` and pass the managed object as `sender`

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
   {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: parties[indexPath.row])
   }
   ```
2. In `DetailViewController` declare a `NSManagedObject` property.

   ```
   class DetailViewController: UIViewController
   {

       var party : NSManagedObject!

       ...
   ```
3. Implement `prepare(for segue` and assign the `NSManagedObject` object to the temporary property.

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       guard segue.identifier == "mySegue" else { return }
       let detailViewController = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
       detailViewController.party = sender as! NSManagedObject
   }
   ```
4. In `viewDidLoad` of `DetailViewController` assign the properties to the outlets.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad()
   {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      nameField.text = party.value(forKey: "name") as? String
      sizeField.text = party.value(forKey: "size") as? String
      contactField.text = party.value(forKey: "contact") as? String
      locationField.text = party.value(forKey: "location") as? String
   }
   ```

Comment: sorry if I showed the code weird, my segue is on my mainviewcontroller, and would you be able to show a snippet for 2-4? I've limited knowledge on how to use core data outside what the tutorial shows. I would really appreciate the lesson

Comment: thank you! I updated the code and ran into this "Could not cast value of type 'Final.PartyCell' (0x10ca8e138) to 'NSManagedObject' (0x10d85dda0)." on the line detailViewController.party = sender as! NSManagedObject . I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes it is. ***First*** I proposed the answer without sample code and the OP asked me to add it.

Comment: @AlexanderQuinto You have to connect the segue from the view controller rather than from the table view cell in Interface Builder otherwise you have to change a couple of lines.

Comment: what changes would I need to make? I deleted the segue from the cell and created a new one from the mainVC to the deatilVC with the same "mySegue" identifier but now nothing happens when I select a cell

Comment: Is the `delegate` of the table view set (in Interface Builder or in code)? I guess it's not. Preferable connect it in Interface Builder

Comment: If you are able to help again, I'm trying to be able to make changes in the detail view textfields in order to update the selected cell/record, would I do this same process but in the returning direction?

Comment: `NSManagedObject` is reference type. Just save the context, go back and reload the table view.

Comment: you are a life saver thank you so much. Core Data is still tricky to me thank you for making it more digestible

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a var in your detailviewcontroller:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController { 
    var party: Party!
}
```

using segue to pass the selected party; so in `didSelectRowAt`

```
let destinationVC = UIStoryboard(name: "yourStory", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourId") as! DetailViewController()
destinationVC.party = selectedParty
destinationVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
```

then in your `viewDidLoad`  of your `DetailViewController` setup your outlets:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   nameField.text = party.something
//and so on!
}
```

Comment: Im having trouble assigning destinationVC.party = selectedParty , it says I can't assign an NSManagedObject to type Party.  I assume instead of var party:Party I need to use an NSManagedObject but I am not sure how to declare it in that way